# background image loop transition CSS3

Tags: css

Okay so the background of my .featured section works perfectly how I want it to transition.

But how do I make it loop? I.E go 0%, 33%, 66%, 0% etc?

```
@-webkit-keyframes test{
0% {
    background-image: url('../img/15.jpg');
}
33% {
    background-image: url('../img/151.jpg');
}
66% {
    background-image: url('../img/152.jpg');
} 
}
/*Featured Content Background*/
.featured { 
background-image: url('../img/15.jpg');
width: 100%;
height: 470px;
margin: auto 0px;
margin-top: -446px;
-webkit-transition: margin-top 1s;
transition-delay: margin-top 0.2s;

-webkit-animation-name: test;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-iteration-count: 2;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmRyM/

ANSWER is to use the correct syntax with a default background image

```
@-webkit-keyframes test{
0% {
    background-image: url('http://www.polydevs.com/mystery/img/15.jpg');
}
33% {
    background-image: url('http://www.polydevs.com/mystery/img/151.jpg');
}
66% {
    background-image: url('http://www.polydevs.com/mystery/img/152.jpg');
}
}
/*Featured Content Background*/
.featured { 
background-image: url('http://www.polydevs.com/mystery/img/15.jpg');
width: 100%;
height: 470px;
margin: auto 0px;
/*margin-top: -446px;*/
-webkit-transition: margin-top 1s;
transition-delay: margin-top 0.2s;

-webkit-animation-name: test;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: Please add a working sample on http://www.jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Okay http://jsfiddle.net/gmRyM/

Comment: Fixed. Added the answer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out :

```
@-webkit-keyframes test{
0% {
    background-image: url('http://www.polydevs.com/mystery/img/15.jpg');
}
33% {
    background-image: url('http://www.polydevs.com/mystery/img/151.jpg');
}
100% {              //Complete the loop.
    background-image: url('http://www.polydevs.com/mystery/img/152.jpg');
    }
}

.featured { 
/*background-image: url('../img/15.jpg');*/
width: 100%;
height: 470px;
margin: auto 0px;
/*margin-top: -446px;*/
-webkit-transition: margin-top 1s;
transition-delay: margin-top 0.2s;

-webkit-animation-name: test;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; --> add this line. 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/St69h/1/)

Comment: I managed to realize that I'd not used the correct syntax, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

While you already found the misspelt `-webkit-iteration-count` which has to be `-webkit-animation-iteration-count`, the true solution for the loop is not to specify a default image, but to actually complete the animation - it doesn't have keyframes now between 66% and 100%. Add a keyframe at 100% to actually make it loop correctly.

<kbd>[**Fiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/gmRyM/7/)</kbd>